# Bootstrap accordion inside modal only works the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-accordion

I have a bootstrap modal windows with an accordion(panel-group) inside an angular ng-repeat, see code below. After the first time I open the modal everything works fine, but if I close the modal, next time the accordions stop working. Please help...

Thanks.

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="p in persons">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{p.Id}}">
                                <strong>Name:</strong> {{p.Name}}
                                <strong>Birthdate:</strong> {{p.BirthDate}}
                                <strong>Sex:</strong> {{p.Sex}}
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="{{p.Id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-repeat="o in p.Orders">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <strong>Date:</strong> {{o.Date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}<br />
                                <strong>Description:</strong> {{o.Description}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try use UI Bootstrap. see this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/